# scanf gets skipped, even with safeties (getchar())

Tags: c, input, stdin, scanf, fflush

I know this question gets asked a hundred times over, and I've scoured all of the possibilities, but I guess I'm not adept enough to know where this problem lies. I'm programming a program where I need to fill a struct with data (ints and strings). The first time I tried it it skipped over everything but the first one, but I didn't panic since I remembered from class I needed to use `fflush(stdin)` to overcome this. Websites I've searched vote against use of `fflush(stdin)`, since it has undefined behaviour. They say using `getchar()` would eat the extra newline, thus fixing the problem. Hence my code:

```
int manNode(){
Item *p;
int helper;
p = (Item*)malloc(sizeof(Item));
printf("Welk type? (Taak:1, Examen:2, Voordracht:3)\n");
scanf("%u",&helper);                           //selecting an itemtype
if (helper < 1 || helper > 3)
{
    printf("wrong value, please try again");
    return 0;
}
getchar();                                     //I've just put getchars everywhere for safety.
p->entrytype = helper-1;
helper = 0;
printf("Vul een naam in:\n");
scanf("%s", p->name);                          //this one fills in fine
getchar();
printf("Vul een vaknaam in: \n");
scanf("%s", p->course);                        //this one gets skipped if I type more than one letter in the last scanf()                
getchar();
printf("Vul een starttijd in:\n");             //From here on out everything gets skipped
p->start = getTijd();
checkTijd(p->start);                           
printf("Vul een eindtijd in: \n");
p->end = getTijd();
checkTijd(p->end);
```

I know it's a bit messy, but focus on the scanfs and getchars. `getTijd()` also has a couple of scanfs in it that scan for integers, they also get skipped. I don't know where to go from here. (The code isn't incomplete, the rest is just irrelevant)

Comment: Can you show the structure `Item`?

Comment: `scanf` is about the worst possible parsing tool available in C because it tries to do two tasks (read input and break it into pieces) and when the pieces aren't exactly as expected it leaves the input stream in a hard-to-determine state. `fgets/sscanf` makes for a much more robust division of labor.

Comment: You have to check that `scanf()` succeeds every time you use it.  When it goes wrong, it stays wrong.  You should error check the `getchar()` functions.  You should also debug by printing the value you just read, to make sure you got what you thought you got.

Comment: Note, too, that `fflush(stdin)` is defined on Windows, but not on Unix platforms.  Please study what it takes to create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Also, you should really show an example of what you do when you run the program so we can see what's going wrong.

Comment: Use fflush(stdout) and press enter to force the stdin buffer to be handled by scanf.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define a new getchar

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define getchar(x) (scanf("%c", x))

int main ()
{
    char x, y[10];
    getchar(&x);
    scanf("%s", y);
    printf("got %s\n", y);
    return 0;
}
```

**update**: this may be a better approach

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void work_to_do()
{
#define getchar(x) (scanf("%c", x))
    char x, y[10];
    getchar(&x);
    scanf("%s", y);
    printf("got %s\n", y);
#undef getchar
}
int main ()
{
    work_to_do();
    return 0;
}
```

to solve the scanf newline ignorance and getchar (but still scanf ignores whitespace)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define __getchar() (read(2, NULL, 1)) // 2 stands for standard error, we can make the user enter a character.

void work_to_do()
{   
    char y[10];
    __getchar();
    scanf("%s", y);
    printf("got %s\n", y);
    __getchar();
}
int main ()
{
    work_to_do();
    return 0;
}
```

and it's good to take a look at this:
 [Read space-separated values from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036686/c-read-space-separated-values-from-file/18037018#18037018)

Comment: At the very least, you have to `#undef getchar` before redefining it.  I'm not convinced that is a good idea.  It would be better to use an alternative name (perhaps `GetChar`) for the macro.

Comment: The problem is that `<stdio.h>` usually defines a macro `getchar()` so before you do your own `#define getchar`, you should `#undef getchar` to cancel the standard version.

Comment: for my case, I think it's not true, shouldn't the compiler warn me about a redefinition?

Comment: although I think the Ghijs's problem still persists, cause scanf ignores newline character...

Comment: It is unusual, but not impossible, for there to be no macro version of `getchar()`.  And since `<stdio.h>` may legitimately declare a macro for it, it is as well to undefine the macro before redefining it, for portability reasons if nothing else.

Comment: See [Read space-separated values from file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036686/c-read-space-separated-values-from-file/18037018#18037018)

Comment: Redefining getchar is at least as horrible an idea as putting `#define struct union` before your includes. Don't ever do it ever (unless you are writing all of stdio in which case you'd know better).

Comment: I don't emphasis on using "getchar" for the new definition. but thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` works as documented.  Also, there is nothing wrong with `scanf` so long as its function is understood.

I created a copy of your code and distilled it to highlight what you want to do.  You will need to fill-in the rest yourself.

In this code you need to enter a digit and press enter.  Then enter a string and press enter, etc.  Note. the `fflush(stdout)` statement is part of the standard C implementation per K&R.  The `fflush` forces the contents of the buffer out to the console.  This flushing makes for a reasonable user/computer dialog.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    char string[100];
    int  helper;

    printf("Welk type? (Taak:1, Examen:2, Voordracht:3)\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    scanf("%d",&helper);    //select an itemtype
    if (helper < 1 || helper > 3)
    {
        printf("wrong value, please try again");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Vul een naam in:\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    scanf("%s", &string[0]);
    printf("\n%s\n", string);

    printf("Vul een vaknaam in: \n");
    fflush(stdout);

    scanf("%s", &string[0]);
    printf("\n%s\n", string);

    printf("Vul een starttijd in:\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%s", &string[0]);
    printf("\n%s\n", string);

    printf("Vul een eindtijd in: \n");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%s", &string[0]);
    printf("\n%s\n", string);
}
```

This code ran on Eclipse with a Microsoft C Compiler.

Also, let me emphasize that if you enter: 1 AAA BBB CCC DDD and press enter then `scanf` will get executed five times.  In this example, the code would run to completion!

So you need to trace your code logic (in this case a straight line) to see how the scanfs are invoked based on what data is entered.

Hope this helps.  Please ask if more questions.

Comment: This is broken for trivial inputs. If you answer "Vul enn naam in:" with any number of Returns the `scanf` never returns.